# PDO doesn't work. I can't access sqlite3 file from PHP.

Tags: database, sqlite, pdo, php

I use php+ apache on Fedora 16 fc16.x86_64.
I'm learning php and sqlite3 (using PDO). But my code doesn't work whatever.

```
<?php
    try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:./z4.db');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users;');
    $posts = $db->execute();

        echo "test test";
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($post = $posts->fetchObject()) {
        echo '<li>' . $post->content . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';


    } catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e);
    }
?>
```

sqlite 3 is OK, database file is ok,

Output of php -m:

```
apc
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
igbinary
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
memcached
mhash
mongo
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

output of rpm -qa | grep php:

```
php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.fc16.x86_64
php-pgsql-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-gd-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-pear-1.9.4-5.fc16.noarch
php-pdo-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-pecl-mongo-1.2.10-1.fc16.x86_64
php-common-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-devel-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-cli-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-mbstring-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-mcrypt-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-pecl-memcached-1.0.2-6.fc16.x86_64
php-xml-5.3.11-1.fc16.x86_64
php-pecl-memcache-3.0.6-1.fc16.x86_64
php-pecl-igbinary-1.1.1-1.fc16.x86_64
```

After adding some extensions to php.ini it is warning:
Module 'xyz' already loaded on Unknown 0...
so I removed them.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I don't understand... but if you ask about pdo.so:

-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root  101688 Apr 27 17:13 pdo.so

Comment: I'm sorry it' was a brain-o, (brain typo), I meant the sqlite database file. Is it accessible to the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute php via the command line, you don't generally execute the same php binary that your webserver runs. They can be different versions, and almost always have different php.ini and configs.

Use [phpinfo](http://www.php.net/phpinfo)() from a `script run through the webserver`. Use that to find a correct php.ini file to edit, then restart the webserver to make sure settings update.

turn on `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`